# The type initializer for 'Program' threw an exception. When retrieveing the COM class factory that failed with error 800401f9

Tags: c#, .net, exception, dll, typeinitializer

I got the exception mentioned in the title, and its inner exception contains this text:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component
with CLSID {609E6B75-5664-11D4-958C-080009D5C296}
failed due to the following error: 800401f9.
```

This problem occurrs on my 64 bit computer (Win 7), after I moved an entire solution (with 3 projects) from another machine (also 64 bit, Win Server 2008).

There was no problem on the source machine when the building was in progress (the target platform is Any CPU in both cases). The solution was built properly. But on my computer it throws an exception when I start the program.

The project refers to 6 DLLs (written in .NET, but I don't know them well).

I didn't find the mentioned CLSID under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID on my computer, but those are there on the source computer (but I don't know how they got there...). I kind of stuck. I would appreciate any suggestion, advice how to get through this. Thank you.

Comment: Look at the references in the project(s). At least one of them is of a COM component. You're probably missing a software component on your new machine.

Comment: Looks like you have to register the dll's on your box. To do that copy them off the source box and run [regsvr32](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249873) for each of them on your box.

Comment: if you are trying to use COM Component on X64 Machine
you must compile your Dot.Net Code in X86 and not Any CPU.
when registring com component on x64 machine it registers in a specailc registry key under syswowc(Windows On Windows) and only 32bit application are able to use it.

Comment: Strange, how was it working on the previous machine ? maybe the errors is not in the program but maybe the libraries in the computer are old version.

Comment: I tried to register the DLLs with regsvr32 command, but the error message said: The module ... was loaded but the entry-point DLLRegisterServer was not found. Make sure that ... is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.